# Determining location with Wi Fi

Tags: geolocation, wifi

Is there a way that I can determine a location of a laptop/phone connected to my router via a wireless network access point? (I do not want to use GPS... only the access point).

Comment: Do you mean there's a computer connected to your router and you don't know where it is?

Comment: Alternatively do you mean that you have a laptop connected to a wireless access point and you want to know where you are based on that wireless access point?

Answer (score 1):

No. But let's examine why.

If you can get the metrics from the router, which might or might not be possible, you can get the  signal strength. This will give you a circle. But, this is limited, as you also need to know how strong the WiFi card is to determine rough distance. But, you probably know the rough distance your router works under, or the max circle, so this is not very useful.

If you have more than one access point, however, you can use triangulation. With two, the information is limited; three or more will give you a more accurate distance and allow you to extrapolate the strength of the signal.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  You might be able to estimate its distance away, but even that is not likely if you're inside a building.  Various building materials attenuate the signal, so the response is non-linear.  If your router has two separate antennas, and you can measure the signal strengh from each independently, then you *might* have a chance of getting a feel for the direction, but I doubt the signal resolution will be high enough to give you any meaningful data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. However you'll need more than one Access Point and some serious software.

There are a number of solutions available and in-development for Location Based Services in Wi-Fi Networks. As Gregory mentioned above a single AP is not enough to do anything but poor range estimation, however multiple APs do not typically use triangulation to determine the location solution, they use a trained Hidden Markov Model.